# Lastest version of wso2 BPS with WS-Humantask and BPEL4People

Tags: wso2

Is there any chance of trying-out unreleased version of the wso2 Business Process Server?

I can see on the BPS website, that it will support WS-Humantask and BPEL4People spec. on  next release (scheduled June12)

I particular need the Humantask feature for a POC and would be grateful for any info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon 4 Beta, BPS pack is available [here](http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS-114/artifact/JOB1/BPS).

Answer (score 0):

There are samples we are planning to release with the next major release. You can find from here https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/graphite/products/bps/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/humantask/ and try-out them.